# How do I update Elasticsearch timezone data?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Brazil we are having a huge problem related with daylight saving time, because the start date was delayed by the President.

Apparently, my cluster thinks that we are in -0200 at America/Sao_Paulo, but actually we are in -0300 yet.

How can I update timezone data? The linux server timezone data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Brazil change you mentioned was recorded in version 2018a of the time zone data.  You likely have an older version installed.

This isn't related to elasticsearch.  You simply need to make sure the time zone data on your operating system is up to date.  This is in the `tzdata` package for most Linux distributions.